# One-to-many relationship with an external authentication system

Tags: authentication, oauth, architecture, server-side

I am creating a task system. I want to use Oauth or any external authentication mechanism. I currently store the external user info in a user table, but I have my own primary key generated. If I am creating a one-to-many relationship between tasks and users, does it make sense to use the External User ID as the foreign key or my internal User ID?

Comment: Use your internal ID (it doesn't "have" to be a SPK, but that's a different discussion) to represent each user/account. Then you can (if the need ever calls) allow multiple external IDs / account associations for the same user, as SO does for example. The external ID is well, external, and not necessarily 1-1 with users.